# Filter ListView based on if "Favorite" option is selected

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I have a ListView, with a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter. The source of the ListView is an ArrayList with custom objects. These custom objects have a favorite member variable. I want the user to be able to click on an icon in the action bar and toggle whether the list shows all the objects, or just the ones with the "favorite" property set to true.

My first kind of hack-y seeming solution is to create two ArrayLists, one with all objects, one with all the favorites. Then on the action button click, switch the adapter source list between the two lists like this:

```
protected void toggleList(){
  CustomAdapter adapter;
  if (favoriteSelected){
    adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,favoriteList);
  }else{
    adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,fullList);
  }
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This seems like it would work, but I have a hard time believing that there isn't some sort of cleaner method to filter the results of a list view. The only info I have been able to find has been about filtering based on text input by the user.

Comment: sure, implement your own Filter class, return its instance in YourAdapter.getFilter() method, (YourAdapter needs to implement Filterable interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
class CustomAdapter{
    List<member> mTempMembers;
    List<member> mMembers;

    ...

    showFavorite(boolean isShowFavoriteOnly){

        if(isShowFavoriteOnly){
            mMembers.removeAllExceptFavorite();
        }else{
            mMembers.removeAll(); 
            mMembers.addAll(mTempMembers);
            //mMembers = mTempMembers;
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Comment: I liked your idea, however, there is a slight problem. When I call showFavorite(true), it works properly. When I toggle back, the listview displays the correct "full" list with all the favorite and non-favorite contacts, but when I click on the second item in the full list, it takes me to the detail view of the second item in the favorite list. So it seems as if the ListView is updating properly, but the adapter which handles the item click is not. Any ideas?

Comment: How about...
"else{ 
mMembers.removeAll(); 
mMembers.addAll(mTempMembers);
}" instead of
"else{
mMembers = mTempMembers;
}"

Comment: @Zelleat Ok this works, but can you please explain why I must manually change the value of mMembers, vs just reassigning the mMembers variable?

Comment: my original code was wrong because mMembers not copy mTempMembers value, but being mTempMembers. you can create new List<Member> variable each showFavorite(false), and it will work. But that way is little bit dirty, and nothing better for adapter. I want adapter manage just one variable and I change that, and notify to adapter that data is changed. I'm not good at english, I don't know whether my means understand to you, but I think this way is little bit better.